# Создать скрипт по microsoft sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно написать скрипт создания таблицы `table1`, с тремя столбцами (`int`, `char`), пятью строками; заполнить их, и сделать поиск по ним.

Создаю таблицу, заполняю строки:

```
create table table1 (
'id' int(11)  ,
'name' char(20) NOT NULL,
'email' varchar(50) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY ('id') 
) ;
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "id"

Comment: звучит как домашнее задание, покажите что вы попробовали и у вас не получилось?

Comment: У Вас точно MS SQL Server? Потому что, то, что у Вас получилось, на нем выдаст ошибку.

Comment: да, поэтому я и спрашиваю, как это все будет выглядеть в целом.

Comment: не надо заключать имена колонок в одинарные кавычки. ни одна СУБД не ожидает видеть имена в одинарных кавычках.

Comment: Предлагаю начать отсюда: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp, а вообще по строке "CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)" google выдает массу материалов